# [C#]Checking for Ground with Physics.OverlapBox

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am checking for ground referencing a 3D rigid body, and seeing if a small box under it collides with any box collider for a ground object. The only issues that the script sees is in the end where the rotation of the box can't be represented by a float value, as Unity says float cannot be converted to UnityEngine.Quaternion.

```
        [Range(1, 10)]
    public float JumpVelocity;
    public float groundedSkin = 0.05f;
    public LayerMask mask;

    bool jumpRequest;
    bool grounded;

    Vector3 playerSize;
    Vector3 boxSize;

    void Awake()
    {
        playerSize = GetComponent<BoxCollider>().size;
        boxSize = new Vector3(playerSize.x, groundedSkin);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded)
        {
            jumpRequest = true;
        }

    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (jumpRequest)
        {         
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpVelocity,         
 ForceMode.Impulse);      
            jumpRequest = false;
            grounded = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Vector3 boxCenter = (Vector3)transform.position + Vector3.down *     
(playerSize.y + boxSize.y) * 0.5f;
            grounded = (Physics.OverlapBox (boxCenter,boxSize, 0f,mask) !=     
null);
        }
    }
}
```

I know sending entire blocks like this isn't elegant, but I simply don't understand why this "0f" value can't be established as a form of rotation for the box. Everything else should be referenced correctly.

Let me know if I'm being stupid. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Quaternions are not defined by a single floating-point value. A non or *zero* rotation equivalence is the *identity*.

Simply replace `0f` with `Quaternion.identity`.